# How to pass a list of a class but also refer to a specific variable in that class

Tags: c#

So here is a basic example and not the full code. I want to be able to refer to the specific variable in Symbol rather than have a bunch of if statements to know which values to add. I know i could make each instance of DataLine a list but that would not work for my overall goal.

```
public class DataLine
{
    public int open;
    public int close;
    public int high;
    public int low;
}

Public class Symbol
{
    public string Code;
    public string Name;

    public DataLine Day;
    public DataLine Week;
    public DataLine Month;
}

public int AddValues(string lineName, ref List<Symbol> symbol)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < symbol.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        if (lineName == "day")
        {
            sum = sum + symbol[i].Day.close
        }
        else if (lineName == "week")
        {
            sum = sum + symbol[i].Week.close
        }
        else if (lineName == "month")
        {
            sum = sum + symbol[i].month.close
        }
    }
    return sum;
}

public void Main()
{
    List<Symbol> symbol = new List<Symbol>();
    //imagine here symbol has items added and variables in DataLine have values

    int daysSum = AddValues("day", ref List<symbol>);

}
```

Comment: Aside from anything else, why is your `symbol` parameter passed by reference, when you're not modifying it? (I'd also *strongly* advise you to start using properties rather than public fields, and following .NET naming conventions).

Comment: And why are you ignoring the last entry of the list?

Comment: (Additionally, your main method wouldn't compile. It makes it much easier to help you if you provide a [mcve] rather than pseudo-code.)

Comment: Sorry the symbol.Count - 1 is incorrect should be symbol.Count. And i passed by ref because I thought I guess incorrectly that lists must be passed by reference. But as i said i just wrote this out for the question  it's not the actual code which is far to large to post here. Any insight into what I am asking or is it not possible?

Comment: I didn't say you had to provide your complete application - but it's really not that hard to write a [mcve] instead of pseudocode. As for `ref`, I think you need to read http://jonskeet.uk/csharp/parameters.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be too keep the different data lines in a Dictionary using the string value as key:

```
public class Symbol
{
   public string Code;
   public string Name;

   public Dictionary<string, DataLine> DataLines = new Dictionary<string, DataLine> { {"day", new DataLine()}, {"week", new DataLine()} , {"month", new DataLine()}};

}
```

And then access it based on your string:

```
public int AddValues(string lineName, ref List<Symbol> symbol)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < symbol.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        sum += symbol[i].DataLines[lineName].close
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Pass in a delegate which takes a `Symbol` as input and a `DataLine` as an output:

```
public int AddValues(List<Symbol> symbol, Func<Symbol, DataLine> selector)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < symbol.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        sum = sum + selector(symbol[i]).close;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

The call than can use a lambda (or named method) to determine how to get a `DataLine` from a `Symbol`:

```
AddValues(list, symbol => symbol.Day);
```

Of course, at this point you could just use `Sum`, as it's specifically designed to sum all of the values in a sequence, as defined by a given selector:

```
list.Sum(symbol => symbol.Day.close);
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you really want is to accept a `Func<Symbol, DataLine>`, or possibly a `Func<Symbol, int>`. Although at that point, you don't really need a method, given how trivial (and value-free) that method would be using LINQ:

```
public int AddValues(Func<Symbol, int> extractor, List<Symbol> symbols)
{
    return symbols.Sum(extractor);
}
```

You'd call it with:

```
int daysSum = AddValues(s => s.Day.close, symbol);
```

But without the method, you could just use:

```
int daysSum = symbol.Sum(s => s.Day.close);
```

... so really, why bother with the method?

Note that this is more flexible than just using `s => s.Day` as it means you can easily sum the open, high or low instead of the close.

(For all the LINQ code, you just need a `using` directive of `using System.Linq;` at the top of your file.)

Comment: Thanks Jon and everyone else who replied i was not aware of such possibilities. All of these could work me quite nicely. I had only ever read existing question on SO and this is the first time I've asked a question, I am blown away with the quickness and quality of answers. Cheers.